# Inserting a timer in Windows Form

Tags: .net, text, timer

I am creating Windows Form that will validate a text in the richtextbox and get errors depending on the requirements given. My only problem now is that every time the richtextbox changes the validation is being process, I mean every key press. How can I set a timer so that every time the user edit some text in the richtextbox it will wait for some seconds to validate the text, not just every key press they do. To be clear here is my code:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();

    //Requirement.cs is a class where all the functions for formatting is placed.

    Requirement req_obj = new Requirement();
    req_obj.check_casing(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);
    req_obj.check_punctuation(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);
    req_obj.check_spacing(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);
    req_obj.check_abbreviation(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);
    req_obj.check_others(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);

    label2.Text = "Warning(s) found:" + req_obj.error_counter;
```

What's happening is that everytime the user changes something in the r.textbox it automatically validates every single key press. 
What I want is to set timer everytime the user will edit the text, after the user edit the text, timer counts 3 before it perform the specific process. 
How can I do that? thanks

Comment: Why not use the validate functionality of windows forms? Then you can implement your validation code in the Validating event.

Comment: I already tried that, but it is just the same as textChanged event, every key press it automatically validates.

Comment: Using a timer doesn't make sense either, that just ticks randomly against the user input.  Use the Validating event so this is triggered when the user tabs to another control.  Or use an OK button.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

(make sure you use the Forms.Timer is you want the Tick handler to be called on the UI thread)

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Tick += ValidationTimer_Tick;
    timer.Start();

    // ...
}

private void ValidationTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = sender as System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
    if(timer != null)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();

        // do validation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to my question, in case someone will be looking for the answer for my problem.

I set timer interval to 3000 and did this:

```
 private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            errors = new List<ListviewError>();
            listView1.Items.Clear();

            Requirement req_obj = new Requirement();
            req_obj.check_casing(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);
            req_obj.check_punctuation(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);
            req_obj.check_spacing(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);
            req_obj.check_abbreviation(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);
            req_obj.check_others(richTextBox1, listView1, errors);

            label2.Text = "Warning(s) found:" + req_obj.error_counter;

            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use the reactive framework (Rx) then you can easily do this kind of timing code.

Try this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Observable
            .FromEventPattern(
                h => richTextBox1.TextChanged += h,
                h => richTextBox1.TextChanged -= h)
            .Select(_ => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0)))
            .Switch()
            .ObserveOn(this)
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                /* Your validation code goes here */
            });
    }
```

The code automatically handles the rich text box text changed event, waits 3 seconds, unless another text change occurs and if it does it begins waiting again, and then finally runs your validation code on the UI-thread.

It's a nice short and neat way to handle the event and timings you require. You can add the Rx libraries via NuGet by installing the "Rx-Main" & "Rx-WinForms" packages.